# IF Exist - new to batch files

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, command, installation

im new to this so ...

I am creating a batch file to install a few programs on to windows 10 
I have created the basics of it

```
@echo off

start c:\7z1514-x64.exe /S

start C:\UltraVNC_1_2_10_X86_setup /silent /loadinf=VNCSETTINGS.inf

start C:\AdbeRdr11010_en_us /sAll

start C:\protect-latest /S

netstop ImmunetProtect

taskkill /IM iptray.exe

copy /Y \\C:\program files\Immunet\local.xml "C\program files\immunet\local.xml"
netstart ImmunetProtect

exit
```

But i am going to add it to netlogon so how do i make sure it doesnt just reinstall each time users log in? 
Iv heard "IF Exist" would work but cant seem to understand or make it work

Comment: e.g. 'if exist "C\program files\immunet\local.xml" exit' would halt the batch file if local.xml had already been put there.  What have you tried, how did it fail?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.If you want you can put everything in the if brackets:

```
@echo off

start c:\7z1514-x64.exe /S

start C:\UltraVNC_1_2_10_X86_setup /silent /loadinf=VNCSETTINGS.inf

start C:\AdbeRdr11010_en_us /sAll

start C:\protect-latest /S

netstop ImmunetProtect

taskkill /IM iptray.exe

if not exist "C\program files\immunet\local.xml" (
  copy /Y \\C:\program files\Immunet\local.xml "C\program files\immunet\local.xml"
)
netstart ImmunetProtect

exit
```

Answer (score 0):

Think this is what i needed ... i might be wrong though

@echo off

if not exist "C:\Program Files (x86)\uvnc bvba" start C:\UltraVNC_1_2_10_X86_setup /silent /loadinf=VNCSETTINGS.inf

if not exist "C:\program Files\7-ZIP" start c:\7z1514-x64.exe /S

if not exist "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 11.0\" start C:\AdbeRdr11010_en_us /sAll

if not exist "C:\Program Files\Immunet" start C:\protect-latest /S
netstop ImmunetProtect
taskkill /IM iptray.exe
copy /Y [\C:\program files\Immunet\local.xml]"C\program files\immunet\local.xml
netstart ImmunetProtect

Exit